# After a "server's certificat is not trusted" trouble, my app don't screen

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio

When I was coding in Flutter on *Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1*, a new windows of server's certificate is not trusted appeared, I didn't know what to do, I thought that was a kind of attack so I declined the certificate. But know, after closing and reopening the app, when I build it, nothing more screen in the Chrome(web) built environment with a error that I think was already there before when the app was screening  good (I am in unsound null safety mode). This is the error :

```
Error: Unexpected null value.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:5405:11)
    at Object.nullCheck (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:5732:30)
    at get user (http://localhost:65099/packages/epressing/profile_folder/profile_edit_page.dart.lib.js:1252:19)
    at desc.get [as user] (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:5906:17)
    at get myUser (http://localhost:65099/packages/epressing/profile_folder/profile_edit_page.dart.lib.js:1222:73)
    at desc.get [as myUser] (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:5906:17)
    at new main.MyApp.new (http://localhost:65099/packages/epressing/auth_folder/login_widget.dart.lib.js:1078:48)
    at main$ (http://localhost:65099/packages/epressing/auth_folder/login_widget.dart.lib.js:1119:22)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:43063:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:42919:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37493:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:38088:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:38126:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37955:23)
    at http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37112:46
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:42919:58)
    at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37493:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:38088:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:38126:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37955:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:37991:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:43223:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:43229:13)
    at http://localhost:65099/dart_sdk.js:38359:9
```

When I try to build it with Edge(web) built, that print out another the same error. With Windows(desktop) too they say :

```
Exception: No Windows desktop project configured. See https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-app to learn about adding Windows support to a project.
```

(my computer hardly run with android emulator, so I don't use that).

I've tried to download two kind of google server's certificate on internet (which is in **apk** type) and add them, but that didn't appeared in the little windows of choosing files or folder certificate path in the

```
Files > Setting > Tools > Server Certificate > Add
```

How can i proceed to add a server certificate if that is the problem and necessary, or how can i solve my problem ?

Comment: I don't have Windows to test on, but it would seem something like [this](https://ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-trust-any-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-ie11-and-edge-fa7b416cac68) should do it...?

Comment: I don't really know, that is the proble. But i will save it for the next time. Know i re-installed android studio and test it the inner basic starting softwre and that worked fine, i'm trynin to see how can i use it to try to solve my problem with my developped app.